# Action Cable Rails got error " RuntimeError - Unable to find subscription with identifier"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create an socket api in Rails by using action cable.
Then I use chrome add-on to send the request for testing.
I got this error:

> Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET,
>   HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket) Could not execute
>   command from ({"command"=>"message", "data"=>"{}",
>   "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"ApiChannel\"}"}) [RuntimeError - Unable
>   to find subscription with identifier: {"channel":"ApiChannel"}]:
>   /home/lin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.5/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:76:in
>   `find' |
>   /home/lin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.5/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:53:in`
>   perform_action' |
>   /home/lin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.5/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:17:in
>   `execute_command' |
>   /home/lin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.5/lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb:85:in`dispatch_websocket_message' |
>   /home/lin/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.5/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:58:in
>   `block in invoke'

Here is my channel:

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
     stream_from "messages"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def chat data
      Message.create! content: data['content']
      ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages',
        message: message.content
  end
end
```

If you have any experience with this, please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your error says:

```
Unable to find subscription with identifier: {"channel":"ApiChannel"}]
```

Which makes since, since your code sample shows that it's called `MessagesChannel`

Have you tried changing your request?